# Custom button next to input not changing border color correctly with BS3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a custom button next to a input which is not acting as intended. Basically its creating a overlapping border with the darker hint when i use `rgba`. The shadow it adds seems to occur in the latest version of BS and not 3.0.0.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 newsletter">
        <form method="post" action='/' class="form" id="newsletter-form">
            <div class="form-group" id="newsletter-form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control newsletter-input" name="testInput" placeholder="Your email address here.." />    
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default newsletter-btn" type="submit">Sign up</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label class="control-label newsletter-status" for="testInput"></label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

```
 body {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color:#404040;
}
.btn:focus, .btn:active, .btn.active {
    outline: 0!important;
}
.newsletter-btn, .newsletter-btn:focus, .newsletter-btn:active, .newsletter-btn.active {
    color:#fff;
    background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 1.0) !important;
    border: 1px solid rgba(52, 152, 219, 1.0) !important;
    font-weight:500;
    border-radius:0!important;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.newsletter-btn:hover {
    background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5) !important;
    border: 1px solid rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5) !important;
    color:#fff!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none!important;
}
.newsletter input {
    box-shadow:none!important;
    border-color:#fff!important;
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:0!important;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7138/

[image: Hover][image: Normal]

Comment: Actually didn't clearly understand your issue.

Comment: @ketan, the hover is adding some kind of shadow, as you can see its overlapping the input field and furthermore the color is different than the actual border.

Comment: It is as if the left border is overlapping on hover.

Comment: What is the desired result? No border on hover? Different color border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the different border color, set the border color to transparent on hover--you are overlapping two elements with 0.5 opacity, which give the look of a lighter border.

```
.newsletter-btn:hover {
    background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5) !important;
    border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    color:#fff!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

To fix the funny growing thing, set the z-index of the button:

```
.newsletter-btn{
    z-index:999;
}
```

See [this functioning fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7160/)